# How to add parallel ajax calls to continuesly running ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parallel-processing

I have a single page that includes several panels with a graph on each.
First graph is continuously updating by using an AJAX that calls an API with param1. The loop is created using ajax complete event, and call itself using settimeout(functionname, 1000, paramName).

I need to run second graph simultaneously, with calling API with param2
and so on.

I may have 3 to 10 graphs in this fashion, need them all be able to run simultaneously. In other world, I need to be able to turn one or more of them on / off.

what is the basic way of doing this using jQuery / Javascript / php

Comment: is this your own api? or someone else's? If it's your own, then have a single front-end URL that can accept/route parameters for each of your api calls, so you end up doing only one http request, and getting one "bulk" response back.

Comment: Reading this again, I think the main thing you have to take on board is that your ajax calls need to be asynchronous.